# CSS for a HTML Newsletter

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
#Wrapper {
width: 600px;
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
...
</div>
```

But for some reason the wrapper's CSS styling  does not extend the full length of the HTML.

I'm missing something obvious I'm sure but can't see the wood for the trees right now and pasting all the code would just make my post look a mess.

Any thoughts...?

Comment: What do you mean by: "does not extend the full length of the HTML"?

Answer (score 2):

Use tables for emails to be consistent across all clients.

Then you should read up on CSS use within emails.

`margins`, `border-radius` are not acceptable.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/